# Qt QGraphicsScene and QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt, qt4

What is the best method/pattern of using Qt's graphics view and model view framework together?

It seems like Qt should have somehow linked these two things together but did not. Could a QGraphicsItem just hold onto a QModelIndex and that would be enough? It sounds like bad solution.

Previously I assumed it would be better just to have some std::vector's of data, include this in a scene and display some of it in a QTreeView. This made undo/redo and syncing data quite difficult and so I'm trying to learn from my mistakes this time round!

I can't seem to find any definitive answer on this.

Comment: The 2 are really different things. I fail to see the connection. What problem are you trying to solve using the 2 together?

Comment: If you have say, a map editor for a tile map. Then I guess you would want the tile data to be a QAbstractTableModel, but this would also have to be displayed in a QGraphicsView, and also each tile may have data that needs displaying in a QTreeView or some such for editable properties such as "IsAnimated" or whatever. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I am also stuck on this one, could you share your solution? The only starting point I have found is this blog: http://invalidmagic.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/qgraphicsscene-used-as-a-qabstractitemmodel/

Comment: In the end I rolled my own framework instead :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant but since I am currently investigating the same question i thought I will post a brief comment on what i found so far:

The ModelView framework is not as it is applicable to the `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` framework. If you want to have your `QGraphicsview` and `QGraphicsScene` behave in the MV sense you'd have to subclass `QAbstractItem` and wrap it around a `QGraphicsscene` which is the `QGraphicsView`'s model. If you don't need to visualize your model in different views I would not recommend in forcing a MV structure. Here is a discussion about this very topic:
https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11763-GraphicsView-ModelView-Integration